# What's the right way to customize the Optimizer in Keras with colocate_gradients_with_ops=True?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mxnet

I have my workload partitioned on two GPUs (aka, model partitioning). By default, TF/Keras allocates all the gradients on GPU0 but I want to use the `colocate_gradients_with_ops` to spread the allocation across two GPU.

I'm looking for a simple way to do that in Keras. My way was to create a new optimizer subclassed from `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` just to flip the default value of `colocate_gradients_with_ops` (from `False` to `True`) . Also I have to flip it in two methods!

I'm looking for a shorter, more direct way than the one below in Keras.

```
class MyAdamOptimizer(tf.train.AdamOptimizer):
    def compute_gradients(self,
                          loss,
                          var_list=None,
                          gate_gradients=tf.train.Optimizer.GATE_OP,
                          aggregation_method=None,
                          colocate_gradients_with_ops=True,
                          grad_loss=None):
        return super(MyAdamOptimizer, self).compute_gradients(
            loss,
            var_list=None,
            gate_gradients=tf.train.Optimizer.GATE_OP,
            aggregation_method=None,
            colocate_gradients_with_ops=True,
            grad_loss=None)

    def minimize(
            loss,
            global_step=None,
            var_list=None,
            gate_gradients=tf.train.Optimizer.GATE_OP,
            aggregation_method=None,
            colocate_gradients_with_ops=True,
            name=None,
            grad_loss=None):
        return super(MyAdamOptimizer, self).minimize(
            loss,
            global_step=None,
            var_list=None,
            gate_gradients=tf.train.Optimizer.GATE_OP,
            aggregation_method=None,
            colocate_gradients_with_ops=True,
            name=None,
            grad_loss=None)
```

Then I call

```
model.compile(optimizer=MyAdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simpler way. Keras AdamOptimizer uses its own implementation from basic operators. You have to use a custom optimizer for `colocate_gradients_with_ops`. If the purpose is to improve multi-GPU performance, you can try [Keras-MXNet](http://Keras-MXNet)'s AdamOptimizer, we overloaded Keras' Optimizer class and have better efficiency on multi-GPUs. You don't have to change your training code.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the option to switch to MXNet.